# submission format in the form of html

Tags: html, css, forms

I saw two different submission formats, but I don't know how and where the form input format is controlled.

> /WebSearch?search=change&scope=all&web=Main
>
> /WebSearch#q=change

Could they be managed in css?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: No. This cant be done is CSS.

Answer (score 1):

On your html form you can choose a method:

```
<form method="POST" action="something" />
```

which submits the form using a post request or you can use:

```
<form method="GET" action="something" />
```

which submits the form using a get request.

With a post request the values of the form fields (based on the name of the field) are passed to the action url as part of the request body. While in a GET request the values (again based on the name of the form field) are passed to the action url via querystring: `?name=something&search=somethingelse`
etc.

More information about POST & GET here (apologies for the W3 link): http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: i would suggest http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html instead w3schools , but w3schools link is also fine in that case

Comment: yeah thanks for that, will definately keep that in mind, i don't like linking w3schools but it seemed ok for this topic :)

Comment: Thanks guys a lot.I checked the html. Both of them are using 'Get'. Then later on, I found there is a function in javascript which possibly change the format to fit the solr search engine. I'll check more and update it once I found something solid.